# Azure: blob uri null when creating image from VM

Tags: image, azure, virtual-machine

I am using the Azure CLI v2.0 and when I try to create an image from a VM, the blob URI is null: 
    {
      ...
      "osDisk": {
        "blobUri": null,
        ...
       }
      ...
    }

I followed the steps from the [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/capture-image?toc=%2fazure%2fvirtual-machines%2flinux%2ftoc.json) and I used a Ubuntu LTS VM created on the Azure portal.

The weird thing is that I already created an image from a VM and at this time, I had a blob URI for my image.

I need the blob URI to get the SAS in order to publish an app in the Azure marketplace.

Also, the URI does not appear in the Azure portal as well and if I try to create a VM from this image, it is successful.

Does anyone have any suggestion on why this is happening?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean you can't find the URI of your new image?

Comment: Yes and no: I do not know if I can't find it or if it was not created as I cannot find it on the Azure portal nor using the Azure Storage Explorer tool.

Comment: Use CLI 2.0 create azure image, this image not store in storage account, you can find it in `images`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, we create image with CLI 2.0, the new create image **not** store in Azure storage account, we can find it in `images`:
[image]

========================================================
**Update**:
Create a image from a **managed** disk, we can't find the URI in Azure portal:
[image]

For now, we **can't** create SAS for managed image.
In your scenario, I think we should use **snapshots**. A snapshot is a copy of a disk at the point in time it is taken, it only applies to one disk. If you have a VM that only has one disks(the OS), we can take a snapshot of it(we should generalize it first).

After snapshot created, we can grant access to this snapshot, also we can copy this snapshot to target Azure subscription. Then we can use this snapshot to create a image and use this image to create a new vm.(snapshot can copy to a different region.)

About create SAS of this snapshot, we can use **CLI 2.0** to do it.

```
C:\Users\jason>az snapshot grant-access --help

Command
    az snapshot grant-access: Grant read access to a snapshot.

Arguments
    --duration-in-seconds [Required]: Time duration in seconds until the SAS access expires.

Resource Id Arguments
    --ids                           : One or more resource IDs (space delimited). If provided, no
                                      other 'Resource Id' arguments should be specified.
    --name -n                       : The name of the snapshot.
    --resource-group -g             : Name of resource group. You can configure the default group
                                      using `az configure --defaults group=<name>`.
```

More information about create new VM with snapshot, please refer to this [link](https://michaelcollier.wordpress.com/2017/05/03/copy-managed-images/).

How to create a managed image from a snapshot, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/capture-image-resource#create-a-managed-image-from-a-snapshot-using-powershell).

**Update2**:

we can use powershell to copy managed disk to azure storage account:

```
##create $SAS
$sas = Grant-AzureRmDiskAccess -ResourceGroupName shui -DiskName test -DurationInSecond 3600 -Access Read 
$destContext = New-AzureStorageContext –StorageAccountName contosostorageav1 -StorageAccountKey 'YourStorageAccountKey' 
Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy -AbsoluteUri $sas.AccessSAS -DestContainer 'vhds' -DestContext $destContext -DestBlob 'MyDestinationBlobName.vhd'
```

Update3:
We can use CLI 2.0 to copy snapshot to azure storage account:

```
az account set --subscription $subscriptionId

sas=$(az snapshot grant-access --resource-group $resourceGroupName --name $snapshotName --duration-in-seconds $sasExpiryDuration --query [accessSas] -o tsv)

az storage blob copy start --destination-blob $destinationVHDFileName --destination-container $storageContainerName --account-name $storageAccountName --account-key $storageAccountKey --source-uri $sas
```

More information about copy snapshot to storage account, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/scripts/storage-linux-cli-sample-copy-snapshot-to-storage-account).

Comment: No, I get the image but not the blob uri of the OS disk which I need to generate a SAS:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsN5M.png

Comment: @Gabriel for now, we can't grant access to managed image. As a workaround, maybe we can use snapshot to do it, we can copy snapshot to different regions, and use this snapshot to create a new managed image, then use this image to create new VM. I have update my answer, please check it.

Comment: Thank you for this but I follow the steps but I think this would not work to get a correct SAS for a SKU for an application on the Azure Marketplace: as detailed in the doc (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/marketplace-publishing/marketplace-publishing-vm-image-creation). The SAS URI must contain sr=c to state the container access-level and sp=rl to state the read and list access to the blob container. Here with the snapshot I only get sr=b and as I understood it, the SAS of a snapshot is read only. Also, I successfully created an image with the blob URI last month for a previous version

Comment: @Gabriel Does this VM new created?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your question. I created a VM from an existing image of mine, is that what you are asking?

Comment: @Gabriel OK, your new create VM is managed disk, we can copy the managed disk to Azure storage account, then use this VHD to create image for Azure Marketplace.

Comment: @Gabriel we can use powershell to copy managed disk to azure storage account, I have update my answer, please check it.

Comment: Thank you for that, is there any way to do it with the Azure CLI? Indeed, I am not on a windows computer but on an UNIX one.

Comment: @Gabriel  we can use CLI 2.0 to copy managed snapshot to azure storage account, so we can create a snapshot, then copy it to azure storage account, please refer to this link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/scripts/storage-linux-cli-sample-copy-snapshot-to-storage-account

Comment: Thank you very much it seems to work. I will try to create the app on the marketplace with this SAS :) I'll keep you updated

Comment: Hi, it worked perfectly, our application is in preview with the blob created from the snapshot, thank you very much :)

Comment: But how to do this if you want to use it for a VMss where you need an Image to create new VMs? Or is there a way to create a Vmss this from a Snapshot?